# New Data Plotly and get_symbol_color()

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, dataplotly

I have update Dataplotly to the last version. There is a new function, that is able to pick the same color of the map, for the different plots (`get_symbol_color()`).

As you can see [here](https://github.com/ghtmtt/DataPlotly/issues/299), this function doesn't work on my computer, and also not on different colleagues.

As I am the only one that have this problem on Github, I just want to know if this function also work for some of you or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[disclaimer: I'm the creator of the function]

As I commented, it's a QGIS 3.22 bug: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/48090

If you want to use this function you have to upgrade to a QGIS >= 3.24